# Review audits shouldn't show me my own posts

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I was going through the close vote review queue when [I received an audit for my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7231108). This feels a little wrong.

I don't know if this is a real problem—it's probably fairly rare, and I can't imagine it really skewing audits at all—but I figured I would point it out. (Also, [the Tavern suggested I post it](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3117040#3117040), so go blame them.)

Honestly, it might even serve its purpose—it certainly caught my attention, though perhaps not in the way audits are supposed to. If it's deemed too minor to fix, fine, but it probably wouldn't hurt to change, and I can't imagine it would be terribly difficult to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code that tries to find an existing review audit task (which was possibly created for another user who skipped / didn't complete it) before querying for a new one didn't check against the user specific rules at all. Thanks for reporting this, the chances of ever getting such a review audit are not exactly big...

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.3.10.3164` on meta, `2015.3.10.2376` on sites).

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree with you. You should be filtered out from reviewing your own question as audit.

Why?

- You can't review your own question, so it is clearly an audit. This defeats the purpose of a review.
- You know what happened to the question. Was it heavily downvoted or upvoted? This would be an indicator what to click, since these metrics are used to determine if it is a bad or good question.

That's why I think this question should be classified as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), not a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 0):

> Honestly, it might even serve its purpose—it certainly caught my attention, though perhaps not in the way audits are supposed to

I believe that it is exactly what audits are supposed to do: to check if **you really pay attention to the posts which you are reviewing** and not a robo-reviewer. It doesn't matter who is the author.

As you noticed that this question was yours, you are paying attention to the posts you are reviewing and therefore you are not a robo-reviewer. That's my opinion.

Comment: But how much of a test is seeing a question that is clearly an audit? I think the audits are also supposed to protect against poor reviewers, not just robo-reviewers.